# Register two FreeDrag gestures

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, gestures

How can you read two gestures at the same time. I'm currently developing a game where two players should use the FreeDrag gesture.

What happens now is:

When player A starts, and he is dragging it works perfectly. If player B then also starts it's FreeDrag gesture, the `TouchPanel.ReadGesture();` doesn't register it until player  A's gesture is finished.

I use the following code:

In `Initialize()`

`TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.FreeDrag;`

In `Update()`

```
if (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
{
    GestureSample touch = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();

    if (touch.GestureType == GestureType.FreeDrag)
    {
        if (touch.Position.Y > GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height/2)
        {
            //logic Player A here
        }
        else
        {
            //logic Player B there
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I noticed you were involved in the "Healthcare IT" Stack exchange and thought you might be interested in this proposal -> [Healthcare Industry](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41370/healthcare-industry?referrer=kaxVuDLRWM_Z_15aCbzplg2)

Answer (score 0):

You have an example in the MSDN documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff827740.aspx

```
// get any gestures that are ready.
while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
{
    GestureSample gs = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();
    switch (gs.GestureType)
    {
        case GestureType.VerticalDrag:
            // move the poem screen vertically by the drag delta
            // amount.
            poem.offset.Y -= gs.Delta.Y;
            break;

        case GestureType.Flick:
            // add velocity to the poem screen (only interested in
            // changes to Y velocity).
            poem.velocity.Y += gs.Delta.Y;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I read that. Except it doesn't register both gestures at the same time (it's essentially the same as the example I've provided).

Answer (score 0):

You can't, `FreeDrag` isn't a multitouch gesture, you should try using `TouchLocation` and `TouchCollection` which let you detect multitouch. Unfortunately you can't use default gestures you've declared in `TouchPanel.EnabledGestures`.