# Handle only one FreeDrag gesture Monogame XNA

Tags: c#, xna, gesture, monogame

I got a small issue. I got a game running on windows 8 but there is a small bug in it. We drag the player around by a FreeDrag event but the problem is when you're dragging the bird around and placing a finger on the other side of the screen en start dragging you will start another FreeDrag event and influence the movement of the bird.

So my question is can I handle only 1 FreeDrag instead of both? someone asked something comparing [individually handle gesture's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226432/register-two-freedrag-gestures) but didn't got an answer on it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you should place another finger on the screen?

Comment: You wouldn't really do it intentionally but if you accidentally touch the screen with another finger or you hit the screen yourself the player will make an unexpected move. The game is an evading game and also by touching the screen with a second finger you could boost yourself and get double speed and so gain an unfair advantage by knowing and executing it properly. Besides all that is it also something thats handy to know for further development (2 player support) and for any other games we may make in the future :)

Comment: I don't think you can handle that, FreeDrag is not a multitouch gesture in XNA, this means that if you touch the screen with another finger you start another drag gesture.

Comment: So I need to fix this particullary issue dirty by saving last position then take the new position and extract the delta to check if it is the ongoing drag and then update my position (if this even works)?

Comment: That seems quite complicated. My suggestion is to avoid FreeDrag and use TouchLocation instead to move your bird.

Comment: Okay, thanks I'll start looking into it tomorrow. Could you maybe repost this advice as an answer then if this works for me I can accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can handle that, `FreeDrag` is not a multitouch gesture in XNA, this means that if you touch the screen with another finger you'll start another drag gesture.
My suggestion is to avoid `FreeDrag` and use `TouchLocation` instead to move your bird. It's easier to handle and combined with `TouchCollection` detects multitouch gestures.

Comment: Hey, I've putted your advise into my game but it created a new bug. When I now head back to the main menu where I use a mix of gestures and touchcollection then my game freezes on the gestures :/ I'm writing a bigger post/question and will put a link >Here< when its finished